# cross-domain ajax to foreign domain with pure JS and html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

First of all - I have read teens of SO similar questions and other googled pages / blogs.

There was many ways to make cross-domain communication work, but is there something that lets me do that, when I'm unable to modify page (for example http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=True%20Grit&y=1969 ) that I want call?

Can I use `postMessage solution` (this method looked best to me) without **ANY modification** in http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=True%20Grit&y=1969 ? It looks like it has no helper page (one of the methods).

I don't want to use any 3rd party library / php script / etc - just pure html and javascript - is it possible to call such a 'immutable' page? ... and parse it on my own page (simple iframe is ofc not enough)

Please help - my huge research leave me with nothing

Comment: Do u have jquery? If so i'll post a solution.

Comment: @Moe Sweet, I know it's easy with jqeury (and easyxdm and so on) - I realy did some search, trust me :) but "I don't want to use any 3rd party library / php script / etc - just pure html and javascrip".

Comment: Then forget about the jquery plugin and you can do native HTML5 postMessage. I'm now working on the exact same thing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here's the thing. what that did is requested data from the same domain. inter-subdomain and subdomain-domain requests are not "same domain", just to make things clear. Since that page was "same-domain", it was possible without a helper.

AJAX does not allow cross-domain requests. as far as i know, there are methods that allow cross-domain requests (such as helper pages)

currently, jsonp is supported by jQuery and you can do it like this:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

look for in the page: "Loads the four most recent cat pictures from the Flickr JSONP API."

or see reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Sorry, jquery is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you'll need a proxy iframe with the same domain where the ajax page lies.

1. postMessage from parent page to iframe page.
2. And then ajax from iframe.

If you dont have access to the parent page's source code, you can inject your script via a bookmarklet or so. Injection can also include jquery and the postMessage plugin along with your script that creates an iframe.

I'm using this postMessage plugin and it works on latest IE/FF/Chrome/Safari with HTML5. It claims to have URL #ing fallback for older browsers but I haven't tested yet.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

Comment: Can I use `postMessage` without injecting script? In my case - I can't use `Bookmarklet` / `Greasemonkey` or any other script injector working with browser.

Comment: postMessage is an HTML5 feature. It works with all HTML5 supported browsers without injecting any script.

I've seen that http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=True%20Grit&y=1969 is returning a clean JSON data. If you're trying to scrape that data, you don't even need browers, iframes and ajax. You can just CURL from your web server and json_decode() the output and use it as a PHP object right away. Am I missing something?

Comment: with php and Java and any other thing it's easy... but I have to do it with html and js only - can it be done? Normaly ajax wont work - `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=tt1285016. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` because of origin

Comment: Then it goes back to first answer, step 1 and 2. But since you're AJAXing and you say you don't have PHP, I wonder what the page called by Ajax will do.